# My openstack instances can't reach internet

Tags: openstack, icmp, openstack-neutron, floating-ip

I’ve installed openstack all-in-one in Centos 7. But, i have an issue with networking. I created an external network in ‘flat’ form (192.168.242.0/24 with gateway 192.168.242.1), and a private network (10.10.10.0/24 with gateway 10.10.10.1).

my instances can ping the router’s gateway (192.168.242.22), the floating ip (192.168.242.37), and the host (192.168.242.42), but they can’t reach the real external gateway (192.168.242.1) nor internet. The ping's message is: Destination Host Unreachable.
In return my host (192.168.242.42) can ping the tenant network’s gateway (10.10.10.1), the floating ip, and the router’s gateway.
Also i can ssh in both sides, and i've already permited ICMP in both sides.

Could you please help me with this issue? I'm really stuck with that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could your host (192.168.242.42) reach the external gateway (192.168.242.1) ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes of course, it reaches the external gateway and connected to internet.